# How Cross site ajax request was carried out without JSONP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, cross-site

When I try to make Cross-Site ajax call to some other domain, I come to know about JSONP.

Then I have the question of "Before the arrival of JSONP, **How such cross-site ajax requests was being carried out?**"

What are the other possibilities to make Cross-Site Ajax Requests?

Comment: Mostly iframe messaging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)